# How to use promises instead of callback in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to execute a function once the other function is completed. I have used callbacks but would like to use promises. But i am not sure how to go about it.

Below is the code,

```
this.set_function(this.save); //save is the callback method 

set_function = (callback) => {
    const some_var = {};
    this.props.get_method.then(response => {
        some_var.data = response;
        this.setState({selected: some_var});
        if(callback) {
            callback(this.props.id, some_var_data);
        }
    });
};

save = (id, some_var) => {
    const payload = {};
    payload.some_var = [some_var];

    client.update(id, payload)
        .then((request) => {
            this.save_data(id);
        });
};
```

Here in the above code, once set_function is completed save function should be executed. As shown above it works with callback. How can i do the same with promises. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only trick there is that your callback expects two separate things (`this.props.id` and `some_var_data`). A promise can have only **one** fulfillment value — so you wrap those up as an object:

```
set_function = () => this.props.get_method.then(response => {
    this.setState({selected: some_var});
    return {id: this.props.id, data: response};
});
```

Notice that since you get a promise from `this.props.get_method`, we just chain off it.

(Your `some_var_data` was already an object, but it only had the `data` property, so I just included `data` in the result object directly.)

You'd use it like this:

```
set_function()
.then(({id, data}) => {
    // use `id` and `data` here
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle error here
});
```

(Or don't include `.catch` and return the promise chain to something else that will handle errors.)

Or of course, if you used it in an `async` function:

```
const {id, data} = await set_function();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it promising, by returning the chained promise:

```
set_function = (callback) => {
 return this.props.get_method.then(response => {      
    this.setState({selected: some_var});
    return {id: this.props.id, some_var };
  });
};
```

Then chain the other function:

```
this.set_function.then(this.save)
```

and finally desteucture the passed object:

```
save = ({ id, some_var }) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

## Await your promises

Using `async ... await` your function will return a promise that will resolve once your function is finished.

```js
set_function = async () => {
    const some_var = {};
    const response = await this.props.get_method;

    some_var.data = response;
    this.setState({selected: some_var});
    return [this.props.id, some_var_data];
};
```

When you call `set_function` it will return a promise so you can `await` or `.then` it. Like so:

```js
this.set_function().then(this.save);
// where
save = ([ id, some_var ]) => {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would have to have `set_function` return a `Promise`.

```
set_function = () => {
    const some_var = {};
    this.props.get_method.then(response => {
        some_var.data = response;
        this.setState({selected: some_var});
        return Promise.resolve({id: this.props.id, some_var: some_var_data})
    });
};
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
set_function().then(data => save(data)
```

Here's a jsfiddle you can play with.

https://jsfiddle.net/ctwLb3zf/